# `say()` takes `0` positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python

I have a problem, my code don't work. What I try to do is to get `pyautogui` to type whatever I want it to type. So instead of typing `pyautogui.typewrite("Something")` a hundred times, I tried to make a `def` so I could say `say("Whatever I need")`. The message I get is this:

> ```
> `say()` takes `0` positional arguments but 2 were given
> ```

Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random

def say():
    pyautogui.typewrite()

say((), 'I am smart')
```

BTW I don't mean that^^

Comment: Why did you expect your function to accept arguments? Your function definition has no arguments in the function signature.

Comment: I don't think the message could be any clearer... makers of python tried very hard to make understandable and accurate messages. You just have to _read_ them.

Comment: I also tried this code, I don't know what to do :P                                                                   import pyautogui
import time
import random

def say():
    pyautogui.typewrite(input('Type something: '))

pyautogui.typewrite('Hello', interval=0.25)

say()

Comment: In your description of the problem you state: 'so I could say "say("Whatever I need")'. From that statement how do you think that `say` should be defined?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really new to python, started a few weeks ago. Can anyone like correct the code? IK I am as noob as you're going to get it :( And thanks for the respons. And I get it, the definition can't take the argument from without the def.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python function tutorial", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Thanks. Helps a lot

Comment: Actually, since the function you want already exists, you could just give it a more convenient name: `from pyautogui import typewrite as say`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a method is called, it takes as many arguments as are defined in the parentheses after it in the method definition. So:

```
def say_hello(name):
   print("Hello " + name)
```

In this example the argument is called `name` and must always be passed. If you call just `say_hello()` without any argument, you'll get an error.

In the same way, a method can't accept more arguments than are defined. Since `say()` has no arguments, it can take no arguments.

The only way to have `say()` actually write what you want would be something like this:

```
def say(mystring):
   pyautogui.typewrite(mystring)

say("I am smart")
```

Comment: Bro, thank you so so much. Like, you have no idea. <3

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random

def say(something):
    pyautogui.typewrite(something, interval=0.1)

say('I am smart')
```

The `something` is a variable, using as a parameter of the function `say()`.